# Ubuntu 18.04, downgrading gcc from 8.4 to 8.3

Tags: 18.04, gcc, downgrade

I am in the position of using some slightly out of date build tools that refuse to work with gcc 8.4; the latest they recognize is gcc 8.3. I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and when I run `apt list gcc-8 --all-versions` it appears that gcc 8.3 is no longer in the bionic repos. How can I downgrade gcc-8?

EDIT:

I tried installing gcc from [jonathanf's gcc backports](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc?field.series_filter=xenial) like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc
sudo apt install gcc-8=8.3.0-19ubuntu1~18.04.york0
```

However, there are missing dependencies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-8 : Depends: cpp-8 (= 8.3.0-19ubuntu1~18.04.york0) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
         Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.3.0-19ubuntu1~18.04.york0) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
         Depends: libgcc-8-dev (= 8.3.0-19ubuntu1~18.04.york0) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```